# OpenGL Spaceship thruster is not circular at base

Tags: c++, math, opengl, glm-math

I am developing a space shooter game using OpenGL. Trying to create a thruster effect for the player's spaceship using particles. I am facing a problem where the base of the thruster is not circular under some angles of the spaceship. You can see the effect in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2QkXe6yfDA&feature=youtu.be).

This is the code for calculating the circular base :

```
float random = fmod(static_cast<float>(rand()) / 100.0, mSize);
glm::vec3 radius = (mUp * random) + (mRight * random);
float angle = (float)i / (float)mNumOfInstances * 360.0f;

float x = mPos.x + glm::cos(angle) * radius.x;
float y = mPos.y + glm::sin(angle) * radius.y;
float z = mPos.z + glm::cos(angle) * radius.z;
particle.Position = glm::vec3(x, y, z);
```

Can someone suggest any corrections to this code to fix the problem?

Comment: Based on the video, the code above seems correct because this is calculating the position. In the video, the position is always correct -- there is some rotation or scaling that is wrong, but the above code has nothing to do with that. My guess is that your manipulations of the scale/rotation matrix are incorrect, but that's in other code that we can't see.

Comment: @cdhowie I think that's wrong. The code above creates a circular base which has static orientation, always defined by the sin and cos used. I would like to make this orientation dynamic to the orientation of the spaceship, so somehow I have to involve the rotations of the spaceship to the code above or find a way to create the circular base along the back vector of the spaceship but I don't know the math involved

Comment: What I said is correct, and your solution is also correct -- by _introducing_ rotation into the calculation of the coordinates on the circle, instead of using the rotation matrix as I hinted at. It would likely be more efficient to use the rotation matrix to do this; your solution requires doing this work on the CPU, while manipulating the rotation matrix can offload this same work to the GPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was the following for anyone having the same problem:

```
glm::vec3 up = (mUp * random);
glm::vec3 right = (mRight * random);
particle.Position = mPos + glm::cos(angle) * up + sin(angle) * right;
```

mUp is the Up vector, mRight is the right vector of the spaceship, angle is the angle for the specific point (0-360) and random is a random radius because I want a filled circle.